# how get correct clicked pixel coordinates in the image texture used in three js globe

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying do correct mapping from three js earth globe (3d world or three js world) to 2D image (x, y pixel coordinates) by mouse click,
Globe ---> click --> get the x, y coords of clicked pixel in texture.png file.
Before I used sphere geometry with one image texture it didn't work,
Now I used box Geometry with six split image textures then project the cube to a sphere. The mapping still not work.

The [complete code is here](https://codepen.io/sebaaismail/pen/YzQyGdo).

The x somehow is good and correct the y is not correct.
My problem:

1. If click on point on the globe how know which texture file is clicked from the six?
2. How get the correct coordinates of y of the pixel clicked
   What is wrong with my code,
   I used one from the six texture to just debug the results as you see here if click on red point must have something close to : {x: 374, y: 366} but actually having x: 376 (it looks good), the y is far 219.
   [image]

important portion of code:

```
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(
    boxWidth,
    boxHeight,
    boxDepth,
    64,
    64,
    64
  );

  //*
  // morph box into a sphere
  for (var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
    geometry.vertices[i].normalize().multiplyScalar(1); // or whatever size you want
  }

  computeGeometry(geometry);

  computeVertexNormals(geometry);
var materialArray = [
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      map: lefTexture,
    }), ... ];

  var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray);
 var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, sphereMaterial);

  scene.add(sphere);


function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const mouse = new THREE.Vector3();
  let target = new THREE.Vector2();

  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  //2. set the picking ray from the camera position and mouse coordinates
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  //3. compute intersections
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
  console.log(
    `textureWidth: ${textureWidth}, textureHeight: ${textureHeight}`
  );

  //* v1 and v2
  target = {
    x: Math.round(intersects[0].uv.x * textureWidth),
    y: textureHeight - Math.round(intersects[0].uv.y * textureHeight),
  };

  console.log("Height: ", canvas.height);
  //*/
  console.log("target: ", target);
  console.log("red should 374 x 366");
}
```

Comment: Your raycasting code looks like it should be working fine. I think your problem might arise when turning the `BoxGeometry` into a sphere, instead of just using `SphereGeometry`. I'm also not sure what's going on in `computeGeometry(geometry);`, but that might make unexpected modifications to your UV mapping. Any chance you can create a working demo either through https://jsfiddle.net/ or [a code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in the question itself?

Comment: @Marquizzo thank you for your review, i created it in codepen [here][https://codepen.io/sebaaismail/pen/YzQyGdo] , i tried to do it directly in SphereGeometry in [this codepen][https://codepen.io/sebaaismail/pen/ZEKgKBO]   , but i didnt get the y coordinates of clicked pixel right, i found that using BoxGeometry and turning it sphere is good idea for the pupose.